# Cross-stack duplicates?

Tags: discussion

Today, I saw [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1304239/append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file). The first comment pointed out that it had been [answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash). Would it have been appropriate to flag the SU question as a duplicate of the SO question, or is the dupe flag specifically intra-stack?

Note: I have not so flagged it; I don't have enough rep on SU to be able to know whether it has been so flagged/VTC'd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to close as duplicate for a question on a different SE site.

To demonstrate, here is a screenshot of the error I get when attempting to close as duplicate on that very [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1304239/append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file):

[image]